# when an item in a list-group is pressed I want to show more details about the clicked item

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Currently, the page is showing the titles of an array stored in a JSON string.
I want to display the rest of the details in that array after pressing on the title. Either in another list group under the title or on a new page.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
        <div class="list-group" id="mod">
            <div class="list-group" id="details">
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <script>//filling the first list-group #mod
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:8888/php/json-data-modules.php', function(data) {
                $.each(data.modules, function(index, module) {
                    $('#mod').append('<button type=btn'+module.moduleName+'" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">'+module.moduleName+'</button>');

                });
            });
        });
//filing the second list-group with new details
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("this").on("click", function(){  
                $.each(data.modules, function(index, module) {
                    $('#details').append('"class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">'+module.credits+'');
                    $('#details').append('" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">'+module.location+'');
                });     
            });
        });
```

And this is the JSON String:

```
{"modules":[{"moduleNo":"999001","moduleName":"Dynamic Web Development","credits":"15","website":"www.dynWeb.ie","dueDate":"2013-05-14","location":"Aungier Street","room":"4037","lat":"53.338545","long":"-6.26607"},{"moduleNo":"999002","moduleName":"Human Computer Interaction","credits":"10","website":"www.hci.ie","dueDate":"2013-04-09","location":"Aungier Street","room":"2005","lat":"53.338545","long":"-6.26607"},{"moduleNo":"999003","moduleName":"Introduction to Programming","credits":"15","website":"www.jscriptIntro.ie","dueDate":"2013-01-11","location":"Kevin Street","room":"1045","lat":"53.337015","long":"-6.267933"},{"moduleNo":"999004","moduleName":"Design Principles","credits":"15","website":"www.designIntro.ie","dueDate":"2013-04-25","location":"Bolton Street","room":"0130","lat":"53.351406","long":"-6.268724"},{"moduleNo":"999005","moduleName":"Design Practice","credits":"10","website":"www.designPract.ie","dueDate":"2013-01-11","location":"Cathal Brugha Street","room":"0123","lat":"53.352044","long":"-6.259514"},{"moduleNo":"999006","moduleName":"Digital Audio","credits":"10","website":"www.dspAudio.com","dueDate":"2013-05-10","location":"Aungier Street","room":"3025","lat":"53.338545","long":"-6.26607"},{"moduleNo":"999007","moduleName":"Digital Signal Processing","credits":"10","website":"www.dspGeneral.ie","dueDate":"2013-04-04","location":"Kevin Street","room":"2103","lat":"53.337015","long":"-6.267933"},{"moduleNo":"999008","moduleName":"History of Digital Media","credits":"5","website":"www.itsbeendone.ie","dueDate":"2013-03-28","location":"Aungier Street","room":"0120","lat":"53.338545","long":"-6.26607"},{"moduleNo":"999009","moduleName":"Digital Asset Management","credits":"5","website":"www.contentStore.ie","dueDate":"2013-05-30","location":"Bolton Street","room":"1004","lat":"53.351406","long":"-6.268724"},{"moduleNo":"999010","moduleName":"Production Skills","credits":"10","website":"www.webDevPro.ie","dueDate":"2013-04-02","location":"Aungier Street","room":"1089","lat":"53.338545","long":"-6.26607"}],"success":1}
```

Comment: Err thats not PHP, it looks like a JSON string, but not PHP

Comment: You are basically asking us to either design, or design and write code from a Specification. 
That is not what StackOverflow is for, we help each other fix code related issues we are having, we dont write code for you

Comment: oh! its in a php file that we were given. which is running on a live server

Comment: You are showing us just JS, still no PHP context at all

Comment: Sorry I thought it was PHP because it's in a .php file. I thought the second jquery was how to do what I'm trying to do but it doesn't work. that's why I asked for help. obviously, I'm very wrong though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few issues with your code:

1. Outside of the AJAX callback the variable `data` is unknown/undefined. So in your second DOM ready block `data` is undefined. You might be tempted to create a global variable, but that would not be a wise move.

Instead find a way to hold onto the data so you do not have to make an unnecessary AJAX call. One way could be to use `data` attributes; you can store `moduleNo` and corresponding details in each button:

```
button.data('mn', module.moduleNo).data('details',module);
```

2. `"this"` means totally nothing or at least not what you think it means; `this`, though does have meaning, for example in a click event handler, it references the element that was clicked.

Give the buttons a common selector, such as a class, eg `module`, then use that to refer to the buttons collectively:

```
 $('button.module').on('click', function() {
    const moduleNo = $(this).data('mn');
    const details  = $(this).data('details');
    ......
 });
```

**DEMO**

```js
const data = {"modules":[{"moduleNo":"999001","moduleName":"Dynamic Web Development","credits":"15","website":"www.dynWeb.ie","dueDate":"2013-05-14","location":"Aungier Street","room":"4037","lat":"53.338545","long":"-6.26607"},{"moduleNo":"999002","moduleName":"Human Computer Interaction","credits":"10","website":"www.hci.ie","dueDate":"2013-04-09","location":"Aungier Street","room":"2005","lat":"53.338545","long":"-6.26607"},{"moduleNo":"999003","moduleName":"Introduction to Programming","credits":"15","website":"www.jscriptIntro.ie","dueDate":"2013-01-11","location":"Kevin Street","room":"1045","lat":"53.337015","long":"-6.267933"},{"moduleNo":"999004","moduleName":"Design Principles","credits":"15","website":"www.designIntro.ie","dueDate":"2013-04-25","location":"Bolton Street","room":"0130","lat":"53.351406","long":"-6.268724"},{"moduleNo":"999005","moduleName":"Design Practice","credits":"10","website":"www.designPract.ie","dueDate":"2013-01-11","location":"Cathal Brugha Street","room":"0123","lat":"53.352044","long":"-6.259514"},{"moduleNo":"999006","moduleName":"Digital Audio","credits":"10","website":"www.dspAudio.com","dueDate":"2013-05-10","location":"Aungier Street","room":"3025","lat":"53.338545","long":"-6.26607"},{"moduleNo":"999007","moduleName":"Digital Signal Processing","credits":"10","website":"www.dspGeneral.ie","dueDate":"2013-04-04","location":"Kevin Street","room":"2103","lat":"53.337015","long":"-6.267933"},{"moduleNo":"999008","moduleName":"History of Digital Media","credits":"5","website":"www.itsbeendone.ie","dueDate":"2013-03-28","location":"Aungier Street","room":"0120","lat":"53.338545","long":"-6.26607"},{"moduleNo":"999009","moduleName":"Digital Asset Management","credits":"5","website":"www.contentStore.ie","dueDate":"2013-05-30","location":"Bolton Street","room":"1004","lat":"53.351406","long":"-6.268724"},{"moduleNo":"999010","moduleName":"Production Skills","credits":"10","website":"www.webDevPro.ie","dueDate":"2013-04-02","location":"Aungier Street","room":"1089","lat":"53.338545","long":"-6.26607"}],"success":1};
    //filling the first list-grid #mod
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.each(data.modules.reverse(), function(index, module) {
            const button = $('<button type=btn'+module.moduleName+'" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action module">'+module.moduleName+'</button>');
            button.data('mn', module.moduleNo) //if needed
            .data('details', module);
            $('#mod').prepend(button);

        });
        //filing the second list-grid with new details
        $("button").on("click", function(){
            const moduleNo = $(this).data('mn');
            const module = $(this).data('details');
            $('#details').html(JSON.stringify(module));
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="list-group" id="mod">
        <div class="list-group" id="details">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great man thanks. I'm very new to this stuff. if i add this will it allow me to display the json stuff in a new grid?: `$('#details').append('<button type=btn'+module+'" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">'+module+'</button>');`code`

Comment: You're on you're way to learning how to program. If you were to create the grid from scratch using static what would you do? Now that you have some data in a variable how would you modify that to fit the scenario?